# forceIframeTransport and context.Request in HttpHandler

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, httphandler

I have used blueimps [jquery file upload plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) to upload files in WebForms application. The plugin sends files to the http handler which parses `context.Request.InputStream` and uses `context.Request.Form["param"]` that was set with `formData` part of the request.

Everything works fine in modern browsers, but as soon as `forceIframeTransport` option is needed (IE 7 for example) all those Request properties are empty.

How can I get the file stream and form data in that case?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to include the [jquery.iframe-transport.js](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js) file. Without that file the inputs were not created (and therefore not submitted).

Also I had to change the way `formData` is treated (as simple `formData.someProperty` was not there - you have to use `formData[0].name / value`)
and the response was returned as a html page (instead of plain json).